# Using Aggregate Function in SubTable in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, count, aggregate-functions

I am trying to put together a Subtable on my report in Visual Studio 2008 with SSRS. The problem I am running into is using a function correctly and referencing a report item via my main report. On my report I have an expression that color codes, when a specific value is returned from the main query. In my Subtable, I want to count each instance of a specific value so for example:

```
Main Report

Supervisor            Employee   Ranking 
Supervisor 1          Employee 1  Meets (Labeled Orange)
Supervisor 1          Employee 2  Outstanding (Labeled Yellow)
Supervisor 2          Employee 3  Meets
Supervisor 2          Employee 4  Meets

Subtable              Outstanding     Meets
Supervisor 1              1            1
Supervisor 2              0            2
```

I have tried using the following formulas

```
=count(Reportitems!Ranking.Value, "Meets", 0)
=count(Reportitems!Ranking.Value, "Orange", 0)
=count(Reportitems!Ranking.Value = "Meets")
=count(Reportitems!Ranking.Value = "Orange")
```

I have also changed     `=count` to     `=countrows` and     `=countdistinct`

Can someone help? I am open to anything, I just want the report and Subtable to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got a table grouped by **Supervisor** (and it looks like you do), you'll need to add a couple of columns with two conditional expressions:

*Outstanding* column:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Ranking.Value = "Outstanding", 1, 0))
```

*Meets* column:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Ranking.Value = "Meets", 1, 0))
```

These will count the occurrences of *Outstanding* and *Meets* for each **Supervisor** that is returned.

This assumes that `Ranking` is just column in your Dataset - you mention colour coding based on this, but we are only interested in the base value, not the colour.

**Edit after comment**

If `Ranking` is based off an expression, you can simply add this into the original expressions above, i.e. something like:

```
=Sum(IIf(<MyExpression> = "Outstanding", 1, 0))
```

It's a bit of a generic answer since I don't know what your specific example is, but you can certainly nest expressions in other expressions without issue.

For a more elegant solution, you should consider adding a **Calculated Field** to your dataset - this defines the expression once in the dataset, then you can use it like a normal field within the report itself. This way you would create a Calculated Field called `Ranking` in your dataset, then you can use expressions like the ones in the original answer referencing this new calculated `Ranking` field.

Comment: The value of "Meets" and "Outstanding" come from an expression, not a part of the dataset from the original query. Is there a way to use an expression that is pulling returned data from an expression?

Comment: @user3216484, I've added more detail to the answer.

Comment: When I place it inside, I get the error of "Aggregate functions can only be in headers and footers." I tried to add the column to the query, but since we have constantly changing numbers and ranking as more money collected comes in, I was not able to get it to work. =iif(fields!KPO.Value is nothing,iif(Fields!Score.Value >= ReportItems!K_Score.Value, "E", iif(Fields!Score.Value >= ReportItems!K_Score2.Value, "M", "OP")), "OS") is the expression I use to calculate the Value, but I can't get it to work in the query due to the need for conditional scoring.